# How to use CitrusSprite.velocity

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, starling-framework, citrus-engine

I have the following function in a scene that extends `citrus.core.starling.StarlingState` - it loads the `PlayerRun` animation and displays it on the screen. For the most part, this code works: I see the sprite on the screen (it's running in place).

```
protected final override function DrawScene ():void
{
    Player = new CitrusSprite ( "Player" );

    Player.velocity = [60, 0]; // Doesn't seem to have an effect
    Player.x = 40;
    Player.y = 40;

    var oClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip ( Resources.getTextures ( 
        "PlayerRun" ), 24 );

    Player.view = oClip;

    add ( Player );
}
```

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use the [`velocity`](http://citrusengine.com/api/citrus/objects/CitrusSprite.html) property - there's no documentation for it and no matter what numbers I use in the code above, it doesn't change the display: the animation plays but the sprite is stationary (it doesn't move horizontally as I would expect it).

Am I using the `velocity` property incorrectly? Does Citrus support sprite velocity or is this something I'd have to implement myself?

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, `CitrusSprite` has a property, `updateCallEnabled` that's `false` by default and disables calls to `update()`. Once I set this property to `true`, the code started working as expected.

Comment: Good to know, nice find.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Citrus yet, but looking at the source code it should work the way you've gone about it assuming that the `update` method is called on your player:

You can review the way the `velocity` property works at these locations:

- The [getter](https://github.com/DaVikingCode/Citrus-Engine/blob/master/src/citrus/objects/CitrusSprite.as#L134) and [setter](https://github.com/DaVikingCode/Citrus-Engine/blob/master/src/citrus/objects/CitrusSprite.as#L138) for `velocity`.
- [The update loop for `CitrusSprite`](https://github.com/DaVikingCode/Citrus-Engine/blob/master/src/citrus/objects/CitrusSprite.as#L288).
- [`MathVector`](https://github.com/DaVikingCode/Citrus-Engine/blob/master/src/citrus/math/MathVector.as), the type used for `velocity` internally.

I suspect you need to add the player to something that will queue it for updating.

Comment: Thank you for the response - I have the sprite on screen so I assumed that `update()` would be called on it - `add()` is called on the `StarlingState` in the code. I'll probably add an `update` override and see if it's called.